# Select the active word file in Windows Explorer

Tags: autohotkey

I would like have AHK code which can allow open Explorer with the active microsoft word file selected. Word seem to be does not have a command allowing direrctly to get path of currently opened file. However in word select document location allows to display and select the full path of currently opened file. Later I tried following AHK code to select the file in explorer.

```
#If WinActive("ahk_class OpusApp")
;In word highlight the document location box
#,::
send ^c ; copy the file path from document location
clipwait
run explorer.exe /select, "%clipboard%
return
```

So far no luck, it just open the explorer, does not select the file as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going about this the wrong way. Write a small VBA macro which you can store in your Normal template.

Microsoft Word VBA has `ActiveDocument.Path` and `ActiveDocument.Name` which can be concatenated with a `\` between to get a full document name including its path.

Comment: Hello, The reason I want to use VBA, as it may allow to select file for a given path and could useful for non- MS Word application. e.g have full path of a file and want to select that file in explorer. Thanks

Comment: Well there you go. VBA has all that is needed.`ActiveDocument.Path & "\" & ActiveDocument.Name`

Comment: Thanks. Could you please give the full VBA code? It does not seem to be working. As said need to get full path in clip board and select in explorer. Thanks again for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the Full File Path and Name of an Open and Active Word Document in AutoHotkey using Component Object Model use the code below:

```
ActiveFileFullName := ComObjActive("Word.Application").ActiveDocument.FullName
```

Further reading @ MSDN on [FullName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214860(v=office.12).aspx)

Additionally here is the Code you seek, in AutoHotkey using COM.

> Press F1 -> Retrieve the Open Word Document Path and Filename -> Open Explorer ->
>   Navigate to Folder -> Select the File

```
;Press F1 while MicroSoft Word is open.  
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#IfWinExist, ahk_class OpusApp 
F1::
        ActiveDocumentFile := ComObjActive("Word.Application").ActiveDocument.FullName
        SplitPath, ActiveDocumentFile, FileName, FolderPath
        RunWait, Explorer
        sleep 100
        WinActivate, ahk_class CabinetWClass
        WinWaitActive, ahk_class CabinetWClass
        sleep 100
        Explorer_NavSelect(FolderPath, FileName)
Return


Explorer_NavSelect(Path, File,  hwnd="") {  
    hwnd := (hwnd="") ? WinExist("A") : hwnd 
    WinGet, ProcessName, ProcessName, % "ahk_id " hwnd
    if (ProcessName != "explorer.exe")  
        return
    For pExp in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
    {
        if (pExp.hwnd = hwnd) { ; matching window found
            pExp.Navigate("file:///" Path) ; Navigate to folder
            sleep 100
            pExp.Document.SelectItem(File, 1 8 16) ; Select our File
            Return
        }
    }
}
```

Read more about [SelectItem on MSDN.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774047(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I could not find it working. AHK showing error of non-existence function. Appreciate your efforst to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: WinExist() function was causing the error, it was a Type-o. Should be working now. Assuming you don't encounter issues with COM Object errors and Office... Unable to test those at the moment but they should work.

Comment: Thanks again for your time. Still its not working. I am not proficient to find the error in this programming code and to fix it. Thanks

Comment: Well, I apologize, I don't have access to MS Office and the error was in that portion of the code. I just edited in what I was told was the issue, someone else tested the code for me, and it should work for you now. If you need to tweak the File Select portion of the code you'll want to to look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774047(v=vs.85).aspx